# SVN Commit error (SVN on window server)

Tags: svn

I am trying to upload around 828 MB data on SVN server but it throws following error.

................................................................................
....svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: PUT of '/svn/interborosrc/!svn/wrk/bd7fee70-765a-e141-88fb-f99591db3db4/tru
nk/Archived/CAS_BASE/Code_Base/DB_Objects/Procedures/get_tot_outstanding_reserve
.sql': timed out waiting for server

What could be the issue , I have uploaded data in GB's but not encounter such issues before

Regards
Prashant

Comment: `timed out waiting for server` is pretty self-explaining, isn't it?

Comment: SVN is not good for storing such big files...

Answer (score 1):

edit the servers config file (`%APPDATA%\Subversion\servers`). In there, you can find the option

```
http-timeout = 60
```

Just increase that value.